# How to add classes in web.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee, web.xml

I made a login form with this lesson: http://bit.ly/eEcVrE

I install tomcat and mysql, create database and tables. But i cant understanding web.xml.
Advise how to fill it, or give references to tutorials about web.xml

Login.jsp starts, but an error when i fill field username and password: The requested resource (/project1/LoginServlet) is not available.

sorry for very-very stupid question, but i really dont know what do. and sorry for bad english.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually add classes to the web.xml, nor do you need to indicate their locations within the web.xml file.

Add them to the WEB-INF/classes sub-directory of your war file (in their appropriate hierchial directory nesting), or if the classes are already packed into JAR files, add them to the WEB-INF/lib sub-directory of your war file.

The web.xml file contains two very important maps.

1. It maps the URL pattern to a Servlet Name.
2. It maps the Servlet Name to a class.

Once you are sure the class is within the WAR file, you need to verify that you are calling the correct URL.  An entry like

```
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

means that calling

```
http://myserver:port/webappName/HelloServlet
```

will be redirected to the "HelloServlet" servlet.  An entry like

```
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>mypackage.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
```

will make sure that all requests to the "HelloServlet" servlet are directed to the class `mypackage.HelloServlet`, which might be located in the WAR's internal `WEB-INF\classes\mypackage\HelloServlet.class`.  Alternatively it might be located in the WAR's internal `WEB-INF\lib\myjar.jar` file, provided the `myjar.jar` file contains a `mypackage\HelloServlet.class` file.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

web.xml is web  - application descriptor.

> The web.xml file provides configuration and deployment information for the Web components that comprise a Web application.

---

> Login.jsp starts, but an error when i fill field username and password: The requested resource (/project1/LoginServlet) is not available.

It is because you haven't mapped this URL pattern in web.xml

Comment: i know that. but i have problem with writing web.xml and understanding structure/

Comment: how i can mapped URL patterns in web.xml

Comment: ?  and it requires something else?

Comment: I think you better use an IDE like netbeans to perform your editing. In that way you can make changes via a UI and then view the source code by clicking "source" tab and you will be better able to understand what is going on.